# JPA ManyToMany cascade with relation (ordering) table

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, eclipselink

**Data design**

My A entity <-> B entity relationship is done via a R entity. However, R has additional information which prevents the use of @ManyToMany:

```
id  | id_a | id_b | previous | ordering_index
----------------------------------------------
 1  |  1   |  10  |    2     |       1
 2  |  1   |  15  |   null   |       0
 3  |  1   |  18  |    1     |       2
```

**JPA entities**

```
@Entity
// ...
public class A{
    // ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="master", cascade = Cascade.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("ordering")
    private List<R> bList;
    // ....
}

@Entity
// ...
public class B{
    // ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="slave", cascade = Cascade.REMOVE)
    private List<R> aList;
    // ....
}

@Entity
// ...
public class R{
    @Id
    // ...
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_a", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private A master;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_b", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private B slave;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "previous", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private R previous;

    @Column(name = "ordering_index")
    private int ordering;
}
```

The relationship is not bidirectional: the user interface allows adding B entities to an A entity but editing a B entity does not allow editing the `aList`.

**So far: the problem**

upon A creation, update and deletion, the R entities are properly persisted and deleted in the database

1. if I add B to A, A correctly has B in `bList` but B does not have A in `aList`
2. upon B deletion, the R entities are properly deleted but the impacted A entities still have B in their `aList`

**What I have tried**

1. Just to have a look, I tried to add some cascade attribute to the `slave` attribute, it was a bad idea
2. I wanted to decorate CRUD methods for the EJB responsible of B entities: upon deletion, find all impacted A entities and remove the relationship in `bList` ==> failed because of `so-far > 1)`: B cannot identify which A entities it is related to
3. upon create and update operation of A, also update B entities by adding the R entity in their `aList` and proceed to an `entityManager.merge()` operation => JPA error because R already exists (even if I don't have a cascade merge attribute?)
4. fetch a fresh copy of B before B's deletion but same as 2), the B entity does not have an up-to-date `aList` and cannot identity which A entities it is related to

What did I miss so far to have the relationship properly configured?

## EDIT: Solution (draft)

I append the solution to concatenate the feedback of comments and answers. As Chris correctly mentioned, it was about the JPA transaction scope. Before going further, some detail:

1. In R's design (database & Entity definition), there is an unicity constraint between master and slave
2. As there are multiple R entities, generic types are used. However, as in JPA interfaces with generic type are not allowed, I cannot call a.getBlist() from a R entity.

My solution was to dig in my 3rd attempt (*upon create and update operation of A, also update B entities*) as suggested by Chris' answer:

```
public class aEjb{
    // ...
    public void update(A a){

        // by A -> R cascade, all the bList will be updated
        em.merge(a);

        // BUT !!!
        // as the transaction did not end, the newly created
        // relationship do not have a primary key generated
        // yet so if I do:
        for(R r : a.getBList()){
            B b = r.getSlave();
            // I'm here adding r = (null, a, b)
            b.add(r);
            // as r has a null primary key, JPA will try to
            // create it, even if I removed all cascade annotation
            // on b side => I didn't really understand why though
            bEjb.update(b);
            // as there is UNIQUE(a,b) constraint, JPA will
            // throw an exception
        }

        // the solution was to fetch a fresh copy of the 
        // cascaded created R entity. As the primary key
        // is not known yet, I have to go through sth like
        for(R r : a.getBlist()){
            B b = r.getSlave();
            R updatedR = rEjb.findByMasterAndSlave(a, b);
            // I'm here adding updatedR = (123, a, b)
            b.add(updatedR)
            // as updatedR primary key is not null, JPA 
            // won't force any cascade operation, and that's
            // great becaues I don't want any cascade here
            bEjb.update(b);

        }

    }
    // ...
}
```

#### Additional note

So far, `bList` and `aList` are up-to-date. If a B entity is deleted, I have an available `aList` to loop through. However, one more problem occurred: what if I removed a B entity from a A entity but deleting only the link, not any of these entity?

The solution is to avoid the option `orphanRemoval = true`:

Before:

```
@Entity
// ...
public class A{
    // ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="master", cascade = Cascade.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("ordering")
    private List<R> bList;
    // ....
}
```

After:

```
@Entity
// ...
public class A{
    // ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="master", cascade = Cascade.ALL)
    @OrderBy("ordering")
    private List<R> bList;

    @Transient
    private List<R> orphanBList;
    // ....

    public void addB(B b){
        R r = new R(a,b);
        bList.add(r);
    }

    public void removeR(R r){
        bList.remove(r);
        orphanBList.add(r);
    }
}
```

Then I proceed to a similar EJB operation as defined to update the impacted B entities

Comment: Prob 1: you need to add B to A and A to B. Your R is not set to cascade, so changes made to A or B will not automatically be picked up unless they are manually merged.

Comment: For problem 2, it is the same thing. The application is responsible for clearing up references to R when R is removed. You either need to manually remove R from A's bList, or you need to force a refresh of all As that exist in the cache.

Comment: Prob 1: I unfortunately cannot directly add B to A. I need to create R1 = new R(A,B) and then add R1 to A. So far, this is ok. However, if I added R1 to B, JPA will try to persist the existing R1. I cannot create a R2 = new R(A,B) as R2 = R1. I haven't flagged any cascade in R's attribute as it is said that cascade is @ManyToOne is bad practice

Comment: Prob 2: looks like it's another face of the same problem. Given a B entity, I need to find the related A entities to clear the reference. My initial design is to fetch the R list. For each Rx (R1, R2, ...), get the A entity, remove the appropriate Rx and then update the A entity on its own. The problem is that my R list is always empty. Even if data in database are correct, it seems that I misconfigured the `aList` in B entity and I cannot find what

Comment: Who said cascade is a bad practice? It isn't, it just shouldn't be used unless you really need it. You need to merge both A and B when you make changes to it, and you don't need cascade options on the R mappings to them to accomplish it, it just makes it easier.  If you add an R to A, you also need to add that same R to B and have both A and B merged. Use cascade or explicitly merge both separately. If you get duplicate inserts, you are doing something wrong, and need to check what you are merging has its ID values set. Check that you are only using the instance passed back from the merge call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A->R and B->R are two separate bidirectional relationships that must be maintained to keep your object model in synch with what is in the database. When ever you add a new R instance, you need to associate both sides of both the A and B references, and since you are changing both A and B instances, you are responsible for merging these changes back in if they are detached.  There are a number of ways to handle this, the simplest is something like:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
A a = em.find(A.class, AsID);
B b = em.find(B.class, BsID);
R r = new R(a, b);
a.bList.add(r);
b.aList.add(r);
em.persist(r);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

In the above code, the order isn't all that important as it is all done in the same context - A and B are still managed, so changes are automatically picked up. The persist call isn't even really needed, as you have the Cascade.ALL set on the A->R relationship but I find it better to call out explicitly. This will ensure that R is always in the list no matter if you are looking at bList or aList.

For deleting an A, you must do something of the form:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
A a = em.find(A.class, AsID);
for (R r: a.bList) {
  if (r.slave != null)
    r.slave.aList.remove(r);
}
em.remove(a);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Again, this works because everything is managed in the same context. If you are passing this back and forth around through DAO type calls, you'll have to handle merging back detached entities yourself, specifically merging the changes to the r.slave back into the persistence context.

Comment: I felt that I had a JPA transaction issue. The problem is that R is generated when A is detached. When the user clicks on "edit", the entity manager fetches the last copy of A. When he wants to add a B entity as a child, a R entity is instantiated at that moment and is also reversely added to B's aList. Then I merge A, which properly cascade R, but if I try to merge B in the same transaction, JPA tries to persist R in the database but R already exists

Comment: Your answer gave me the fatal hint about transaction. As I'm using JTA, I don't think I have full control over the JPA transaction scope so that was the trick. Moreover, I got tricked by JPA cascade: I'm not sure when primary keys are generated for cascaded entities. I have edited my post with my temporary solution and will confirm later after testing but I have a good feeling about this. Anyway, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constructor like that to solve problem 1:

```
public R(A master, B slave, R previous, int ordering){
    this.master = master;
    master.getBList().add(this);
    this.slave = slave;
    slave.getAList().add(this);
    this.previous = previous;
    this.ordering = ordering;
}
```

Try to follow the same way for the problem 2.

Comment: Not directly in the constructor of R but when A add a B entity as a "child", it already does something similar. I'm merging A, which cascade to R but B's state is not updated. When I simply do a merge on B, in the same method of A's merging, JPA tries to persist R which already exists leading to an exception